# How to draw element above drawer?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

I am trying to place a button above a drawer, like in Windows Calculator:

[image: 1]

but it doesn't work.

Any solutions for this?

UPD: I've updated this post and added an example gif that shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
ToolButton {
        id: drawerButton

        width: 32
        height: 32
        // trying to place above this object
        z: 100

        anchors {
            left: drawerPopUp.left
            leftMargin: 5
            top: drawerPopUp.top
            topMargin: 5
        }
}

Drawer {
        id: drawerPopUp
        // trying to place below this object
        z: -1

        width: root.width * 0.35
        height: root.height

        edge: Qt.LeftEdge
        interactive: true
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be one qml file? You can only ever have one root item for each file. Try nesting the Button and Drawer in a Column?

Comment: This query is missing a lot of detail. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm not familiar with Windows Calculator.

Comment: From your anchors in the button, it seems you want to place the button in the drawer, such that it is only visible when opened? That should just be fixed with placing the button as a child of the drawer. I suggest to read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html it has some nice examples

Comment: @CrouchEndTiger Hello! These two objects derived from class `ApplicationWindow`.

Comment: @Amfasis Hi! I tried to set Drawer as derived class of ToolButton, but nothing happened.

Comment: @EEdle please don't use the word "derived" when you mean it's a child, since deriving means that one class adds some functionality to another class (from which it is derived). You mean that you made it a child, which we generally call "composition". Did you put them in the correct order, `ToolButton` should be _inside_ the braces of `Drawer`?

Comment: I just see you had an image (put it as inline image for you), which tells me, my solution indeed won't get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html) you can read that the Drawer automatically reparents itself to `Overlay`, which is above all the other elements. Therefore you would need to add a button to the overlay itself as well.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    ...

    ToolButton {
        ...
        parent: Overlay.overlay
        ...
    }
}
```

This might get awkward if you are doing more complex stuff, so you might have to copy the button, one in the normal way and one on the overlay

Comment: It didn't work for me. I defined this line and nothing happened.

Comment: Did you get any errors/warnings? And what version Qt are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Qt 6.3 version with Visual Studio plugin. I didn't get any errors and warns.

Comment: I put the ToolBar as a child object of the Drawer and added this line `parent: Overlay.overlay` but it won't work.

Comment: You should have the tool _button_ on the overlay, or is your question not the same as your actual program? Also, could you be more specific than "it won't work"? For me, in Qt 5.11.3, I can mimick the provided GIF with this

Comment: Worked me on Qt 5.12 and 5.15.